# Queue Priority seems not right

Tags: ios, swift

so I am testing out some threading codes

```
private func queuesWithQos(){
    let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.queue1", qos: .userInitiated)
    let queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.queue2", qos: .utility)

    queue1.async {
        print("Queue1 thread: \(Thread.current)")
        for i in 0..<10{
            print("Queue1:", i)
        }
    }

    queue2.async {
        print("Queue2 thread: \(Thread.current)")
        for i in 100..<110{
            print("Queue2", i)
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("I am in main queue")
    }
}
```

And, I think that "I am in main queue" in this case should be printed first right since it is main thread and has the highest priority? But apparently, it is printed last?

I don't get it?

Can someone explain to me?

Thanks!

Comment: That may be helpful for understanding Queue also Why you use DispatchQueue 2 variable , required only 1 here. : https://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/

Comment: @Miteshjadav I am actually walking through the tutorial.. I am testing the queues to furhter understand, that is why I create multi-queues to see how things work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the small amount of work in the queues. In your case even if you increase the number of prints to whatever, chances are that the `I am in main queue` will never be called first.

If you run your code multiple times, you'll see that the `I am in main queue` shows at different states because the `async` command submits the job to a queue, it doesn't matter if it's main or background queue, it won't be executed now, it will take a few milliseconds depending on the load of the queue to be executed.

In your case, the "I am in main queue" job, takes just a few milliseconds to be scheduled for execution, but it's enough time for the other jobs to start executing their jobs (and maybe completing them). That's why you see the other logs first, it's that scheduling time delay.

Also you have to keep in mind that the main queue is in charge of UI display, so it might need more time to execute your job, if there is a rendering in process or other blocking operations.

If you want to have the "I am in main queue" executed first, simply remove it from the dispatch queue. That's something like saying "execute this NOW".

Answer (score 0):

The tasks that you have put inside the different queues are fairly simple. In fact, they are so simple that the entire block will get executed before context switching happens and the control gets passed to some other queue.

Try increasing the range of the `for` loops to, say 1000000; you should be able to notice the difference then. For fair comparison, put a similar loop in the main queue as well.